# How can we add entity framework in one project and use it as a service in another project?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, microservices

I want a project to has entity framework nuget package ,and other project just register this service  in start-up with name of their models. I Have seen mongo version of this approach but I couldn't find any ef one.
mongo example:
In Service project:

```
using Autofac;
using DShop.Common.Types;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace DShop.Common.Mongo
{
 public static class Extensions
    {
        public static void AddMongo(this ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Register(context =>
            {
                var configuration = context.Resolve<IConfiguration>();
                var options = configuration.GetOptions<MongoDbOptions>("mongo");

                return options;
            }).SingleInstance();

            builder.Register(context =>
            {
                var options = context.Resolve<MongoDbOptions>();

                return new MongoClient(options.ConnectionString);
            }).SingleInstance();

            builder.Register(context =>
            {
                var options = context.Resolve<MongoDbOptions>();
                var client = context.Resolve<MongoClient>();
                return client.GetDatabase(options.Database);

            }).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            builder.RegisterType<MongoDbInitializer>()
                .As<IMongoDbInitializer>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            builder.RegisterType<MongoDbSeeder>()
                .As<IMongoDbSeeder>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        }

        public static void AddMongoRepository<TEntity>(this ContainerBuilder builder, string collectionName)
            where TEntity : IIdentifiable
            => builder.Register(ctx => new MongoRepository<TEntity>(ctx.Resolve<IMongoDatabase>(), collectionName))
                .As<IMongoRepository<TEntity>>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}
```

In Start up of web project:

```
 var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly())
                .AsImplementedInterfaces();
            builder.Populate(services);  
            builder.AddMongo();
            builder.AddMongoRepository<Cart>("Carts");
            builder.AddMongoRepository<Customer>("Customers");
            builder.AddMongoRepository<Product>("Products");

            Container = builder.Build();
```

Answer (score 0):

An usual solution has multiple project like the web project if you are creating a web app, the test project, DAL project and so on. I have created a sample to show you how can connect project in the same solution.

1. First create lets say an web application
2. Create the Class Library project where you can create the `EntityFramework` part

[image: Multiple project in one solution]

3. Install Microsoft `EntityFramework` in this project.

[image]

4. Right click on `Dependecies =>  Add Reference` on web project and select the EntityFramework project.

[image]

5. Open the `Startup.cs` in web project add the namespace `using EntityFramework;`of the Class Library with `EntityFramework` name.
6. In the same file add the code to connect with database.

   ```
     services.AddDbContext<YourContext>(options => options
                           .UseSqlServer(Configuration
                           .GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionString")));
   ```

With the same way you can connect multiple projects.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, But I want to not create DbContext in web project and pass models in start up and entity frame work project make custom DbContext itself for each project.